# Perceptual Image Comparison

Tags: image-processing, comparison, video-processing

I'm trying to do image comparison to detect changes in a video processing application. These are two images that look identical to me, but are different according to both
http://pdiff.sourceforge.net/
and http://www.itec.uni-klu.ac.at/lire/nightly/api/net/semanticmetadata/lire/imageanalysis/LireFeature.html

Can anyone explain the difference? Eventually I need to find a library that can detect differences that doesn't have any false positives.

[image: pic2]

[image: pic1]

Comment: The question is well-written.  Michael has indicated research.  Why has someone anonymously down-voted it without comment or explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two images are different.

I used GIMP (open source) to stack the two images one on top of the other and do a difference for the top layer.  It showed a very faint black image, i.e. very little difference.  I then used Curve to raise the tones and it revealed that what seem to be JPEG artifacts, even though the files given are PNG.  I recommend GIMP and sometimes I use it instead of Photoshop.

Using GIMP to do a blink comparison between layers at 400% view, I would guess that the first image is closer to the original.  The second may be saved copy of the first or from the original but saved at a lower quality setting.

It seems that the metadata has been stripped off both images (haven't done a definitive look), so no clues there.

There was a program called Unique Filer that I used for years.  It is tunable and rather good.  But any comparator is likely to generate a number of false positives if you tune it well enough to make sure it doesn't miss  duplicates.  If you only want to catch images that are very similar like this pair, then you can tune it very tightly.  It is old and may not work on Windows 7 or later.

I would like to find good image checkers / comparators too.  I've considered writing my own program.

[image: Difference with exaggerated colour (brightened)]

Comment: I ended up using this. When I used the ignore antialiasing option, it judged the images identical http://huddle.github.io/Resemble.js/.